# What's the differenct between `go tool compile` and `go tool objdump`?

Tags: go

Both the `go tool compile` and `go tool objdump` can print the assembler of go program, I wonder what is the difference between two of them?

Answer (score 0):

`go tool compile` and `go build -gcflags -S` are used to generate assembly code that is in the process, while `go tool objdump` is used to generate assembly code for the final machine code.

Comment: I am confusing about ` in the process`, it‘s that means the Go code I wrote?

Comment: In the process means it's not machine code, it's something in between.